# Class attribute with two double quotes

Tags: c#, asp.net, attributes, updatepanel, bulletedlist

I am adding list items to a Bulleted List control.

In the list item i wanted to have the attribute class="" coded.

See code below. class="" is converted to class and the right side ="" is truncated.

Its very important to note that this happens when the scriptmanage/updatepanel is used in the code. otherwise, it seems to be fine.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMain" runat="server" />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelMain"
                runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

                    <asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" DisplayMode="LinkButton">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1" class="active"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="2" class=""></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Three" Value="3" class=""></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:BulletedList>


                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="myplaceHolder" runat="server">

                        <asp:BulletedList ID="BL_Seasons" runat="server" DisplayMode="LinkButton">
                        </asp:BulletedList>

                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The [`ListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx) class has no `class` property.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    class="<%= 1<2?"":"something is wrong"%>"
```

This should look like class="" in browser.

But some more appropriate thing is to use a different quotation on sides:

```
      class='<%= 1<2?"":"something is wrong"%>'
```